# phpdocumentor 2 not completing the docs

Tags: beta, phpdoc

i'm trying to use phpdocumentor 2 but it's acting a little odd.
I'm running windows 7 x64 and xampp.
i installed it using pear `pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-beta`
the install went ok but when i try to run it it shows this

```
$ phpdoc -f C:\xampp\htdocs\tests\comments.class.php -t C:\xampp\htdocs\tests/build/api/ -i C:\xampp\htdocs\tests/build/api/
Collecting files .. OK
Initializing parser .. OK
Parsing files
Parsing C:\xampp\htdocs\tests\comments.class.php
  No summary for property $link
  No summary for property $error
  No summary for method grabComment()
  No summary for method generateComments()
  No summary for method generateReplies()
  No summary for method generateForm()
  No summary for method isValidMail()
  No summary for method ip()
Storing cache in "C:\xampp\htdocs\tests\build\api" .. OK
Load cache                                                           ..    0.003s
Preparing template "responsive-twig"                                 ..    0.054s
Preparing 15 transformations                                         ..    0.000s
Build "elements" index                                               ..    0.000s
Replace textual FQCNs with object aliases                            ..    0.001s
Build "packages" index                                               ..    0.002s
Build "namespaces" index and add namespaces to "elements"            ..    0.000s
Transform analyzed project into artifacts                            ..    2.961s
Analyze results and write report to log                              ..    0.000s
```

and then it just stops...
when i check the generated docs no data about the class is displayed
has anybody had this problem ?

Comment: Just hit the very same problem, same platform, same behaviour. Investigating...

Comment: let me know if you find anything please

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's due to the incomplete and beta default template `responsive-twig`. There's no error reported because there is no error. The PHPDocumentor just finishes fine without any errors.

Changing the template to `responsive` makes thing a bit better. You may do so by adding

```
<transformations>
  <template name="responsive" />
</transformations>
```

to your phpdoc.xml or providing the `--template=responsive` command line option. I did not try other templates.

In the end I stuck to [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for now until the PHPDocumentor2 templates are more complete and feature rich.